# bash command name starts with '-' (minus)

Tags: shell, unix, authentication

If I run this command from my login shell:

```
$ echo $0
```

It returns:

```
-bash
```

Why does the login shell have a minus sign in the front? If I run bash again, then $0 is just "bash".

Comment: -bash means that  bash was invoked as a login shell. bash means it was invoked as a non login shell. Check out http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell for more info

Comment: Thanks for the link! It's hard for me to search for questions that involve a lot of punctuation like that.

Comment: unfortunately google (and all the other search enginges) aren't programmer friendly... the way they index precludes the type of queries we would like to run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The name `-bash` means that `bash` was invoked as a *login* shell. The name `bash` means it was invoked as a *non login* shell. Check out [Difference between Login Shell and Non-Login Shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell) for more info.